# Quest ActiveRoles Managementshell: FOREACH-OBJECT Set-QADUSER Server is unwilling

Tags: powershell, foreach

I've to update different values on each user in our AD environment (1000+ Users).

I've a CSV file with all values in, the file's format is like

```
SamAccountName,Name,telephoneNumber,ipPhone....
```

I've tried to import the data with the following PS syntax:

```
import-csv -path "PathToCSVFiles" | ForEach-Object {
    get-qaduser -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -SearchScope "Subtree" -SearchRoot "ou=SomeOu,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=local"| Set-QADUser -objectAttributes @{ipPhone=$_.ipPhone}
}
```

But I'm always getting "Set-QADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request." errors for every single userobject.

When I run the whole "get-qaduser....set-qaduser" line with single values instead of running it within the foreach-object block, it works perfectly fine and I can't get the point why the foreach part doesn't work.

At the moment I've an Excel VBA macro that writes a PS1 file with a single line for every single user that needs to be updated, but this is a mess and not really helpful.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, would be much appreciated.

Thanks & Best,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove the get command?

```
Import-Csv -path "PathToCSVFiles" | ForEach-Object {
    Set-QADUser $_.SamAccountName -ObjectAttributes @{ipPhone=$_.ipPhone}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly fine for me, but do you've a guess why it isn't working when running my origin syntax?

Comment: What happens when you remove the set command? Do you get one object per item in csv file?

Comment: Yes, when I just run the Get-QADUser file from the input of the CSV file, I'll get a line per User that shows the DN of each. So it has to be something related to the combination of get/set.

Answer (score 0):

in your second foreach loop $_ refers to the results sent by get-qaduser whichhave not an ipPhone attribute.
Try this instead :

```
import-csv -path "PathToCSVFiles" | ForEach-Object {
    $ipPhone=$_.ipPhone
    get-qaduser -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -SearchScope "Subtree" -SearchRoot "ou=SomeOu,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=local"| Set-QADUser -objectAttributes @{ipPhone=$ipPhone}
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, but this unfortunately isn't the cause for the error, since the declaration of $ipPhone was only lost during Copy & Paste. Basically I tried to use $_.ipPhone directly without luck, too and when I Copy & Paste the parts of the PS syntax to my post I missed to include the $ipPhone declaration. Anyway thanks for your reply!